# jquery sliding div active on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site I have sliding divs with a navigation menu. I dont know how to set one of divs active.

**My question:**
How do I make link go to the sliding divs? For example, one link will be somewhere on website and on click will send me to sliding div ABOUT.

I posting one more time all what i have for this case. solution above looks like not working ,so i try clear this again with more info.  i know for next time.i hope ,its all.and additional question is..why overflow: hidden is not working.

here is it :  http://jsfiddle.net/strme/ezHGp/1/

HTML

```
 <a href="javascript:;" id="home"  class="a">twin2</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="about" class="a">twin3</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="contact" class="a">twin4</a>


<div id="bigbox">
    <div id="home_content" class="contents">
        <div class="mainContent">

           <div class="contentproduct"> 

                <header>
                          <h1>twin2</h1>            
                </header>

           </div>

        </div>
    </div>   

    <div id="about_content" class="contents">   
            <div class="mainContent">

           <div class="contentproduct"> 

                <header>
                          <h1>twin3</h1>            
                </header>

           </div>

        </div>
    </div> 

    <div id="contact_content" class="contents">
        <div class="mainContent">

           <div class="contentproduct"> 

                <header>
                          <h1>twin4</h1>            
                </header>


              </div>
     </div> 
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", ".a", function(){
    $("#bigbox").removeClass(); /* Remove all classes */
    $("#bigbox").addClass("transition "+this.id+"_inside"); /* add 'transition' for effects and eg. 'home_inside' classes */
});
```

CSS

```
body {

    color: #373737;
    font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size: 14px */
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',       'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    }

.body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;   
    }


.mainContent {
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

}

.contentproduct {
    width: 560px;
    height: 391px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 30px ;

}

#bigbox {
    background-color: grey;
    padding-top: 0px; /* test only */
    margin-left: 150%; /* Start position: right outside */
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s;
    -o-transition: margin-left 1s;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
#bigbox.home_inside {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#bigbox.about_inside {
    margin-left: -100%;
}

#bigbox.contact_inside {
    margin-left: -200%;
}

#bigbox.transition { /* Effects only */
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s;
    -o-transition: margin-left 1s;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}

.contents {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: 0;

    }

#home_content {
    margin-left: 0; /* inside the #bigbox */
    background-color: green;
}
#about_content {
    margin-left: 1000px; /* "relative" position to #home_content */
    background-color: white;

}

#contact_content {
    margin-left: 2000px; /* "relative" position to #home_content */
    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: Where is the code that slides the div's? Your JS just toggles classes, whereas you need to also trigger the slider. Post up your slider code or plugin link if you're using a plugin.

Comment: more info now. thanks for help

Comment: For your second question, can you clarify the following : the link on your website that needs to point to the sliding div, is it on a different page? (a page where the slides are not present?)

Comment: yes. i was thinking maybe some javascript will help me. each link have own.html page now, with theirs content set as active in javascript.  so, every html have own javascript. is this right what i doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look here https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/ you will find a nice example of how to use the slide effect. You should first choose the correct selectors and then use the .toggle() function! 
Adding/removing classes is more for CSS styling

Hope I helped a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JavaScript I wouldn't recommend JQuery. But it looks like you know what you are doing. You should put the jQuery in a JavaScript file or in between `<script>` tags. Instead of using the `href` attribute you should use the `onclick` attribute. Like this:

```
<a href="about:blank" onclick="activate()" id="home" class="a">twin2</a>
<a href="about:blank" onclick="activate()" id="about" class="a">twin3</a>
<a href="about:blank" onclick="activate()" id="contact" class="a">twin4</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function activate()
    {
        $("#bigbox").removeClass();
        $("#bigbox").addClass("transition "+this.id+"_inside");
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hm,true. i dont know if i need to add something more to this script. what happend is that sliding is not working with your code.i think is nice but, what i doing wrong? just edited my original post.

Comment: now i struggling with my second question. how to make link jump to other page to defined sliding div. do you have some ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry! I'm not that familiar with JQuery

Comment: i just make more .html files. one for each link.  so i have solution, thanks.